# Split between two date in php bassed on end of year

Tags: php, date

I have case with php date. How to split between two date, for example.

```
$dateStart  = '2015-05-04';
$dateFinish = '2018-06-10';
```

I want the output is array like this:

```
 |$dateStartArray   |$dateFinishArray   |       
 |  '2015-05-04',   |   '2015-12-31',   |   ----------->2015
 |  '2016-01-01',   |   '2016-05-03',   |   ----------->2016_1
 |  '2016-05-04',   |   '2016-12-31',   |   ----------->2016_2
 |  '2017-01-01',   |   '2017-05-03',   |   ----------->2017_1
 |  '2017-05-04',   |   '2017-12-31',   |   ----------->2017_2
 |  '2018-01-01',   |   '2018-05-03',   |   ----------->2018_1
 |  '2018-05-04',   |   '2018-06-10',   |   ----------->2018_2
```

Thank you.

Comment: Explain bit more

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, can we see your code? What are the criteria?

Comment: Yes, I have try

Comment: here my code:
https://ideone.com/doA8p6

Comment: So include your try in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can while loop with the Unix times of start and end then manipulate the arrays depending on if your writing start of year or end of year.

I use the $i to keep track of it's the start of year or end of year.
When the loop is done I end up with last item 2018-12-31 so I replace that after the loop with finnish date.

```
$dateStart  = '2015-05-04';
$dateFinish = '2018-06-10';

$split = date("m-d", strtotime($dateStart)-86400);

$time = strtotime($dateStart);
$end = strtotime($dateFinish);


$i=1;
While($time<$end){
    If($i){
        $startarr[] = date("Y-m-d", $time);
        $endarr[] = date("Y-12-31", $time);
    }else{
        $startarr[] = date("Y-01-01", $time);
        $endarr[] = date("Y-" . $split, $time);
    }
    $i = !$i;
    // Add one day to last inserted end date
    $time = strtotime(end($endarr))+86400;
}

$endarr[count($endarr)-1] = $dateFinish;
Var_dump($startarr, $endarr);
```

https://3v4l.org/50AqX

Comment: Hi Andreas, thank you very much, its works perfectly and the result as I mean. I don't think to use while. its very nice method.